# Internet audio player from java swing client?

Tags: swing, java, javasound

Im trying to implement and realtime audio streaming swing desktop app . trying to get bytes of audio using java.net classes and then feeding it to play .

Just trying blind punches undersea water thinking the water tank will crack :((

help or any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use the AudioSystem class.  this allows you to get the AudioInputStream from a URL.

Comment: Also have are you able to just play a sound file aside from getting the bytes from the java.net classes.  Which part of this ar eyou having trouble with?