# Stream audio from URL in java Swing App

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming, javasound

I want to play streaming audio from server in java swing app.

There's a public live stream available at `http://64.202.98.32:6210`.

I have tried the [java sound API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html) without success:

```
URL ur= new URL("http://64.202.98.32:6210");
AudioStream as = new AudioStream (url.openStream());
```

I also looked at 
[Internet audio player from java swing client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458221/internet-audio-player-from-java-swing-client)

How can I play live audio in swing app?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open-source project called FMJ at this link, maybe it can help -> http://fmj-sf.net/

But IMHO, instead of directly using a service, you may be able to get the streaming data from network with your Swing application, then play it using Java's Sound API.